# Virtual memory mapping reported by pmap -X does not come from mmap system call

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, malloc, system-calls

I have a problem with excessive memory consumption of the process and tried to catch system calls and stack traces with `strace` to get a grasp on who mapped the memory. So runnin `strace -f myapp` I got strace captured all the system calls for all threads.

When looking at `pmap -X <pid>` I found out that there are 2 mappings with the most `RSS` with addresses `0x7d516c000000` and `0x7d5198000000`. When `grep`ing the `strace` output for the addresses I got only the following result:

```
$ grep 7d5198000000 strace.txt 
[pid  9734] mprotect(0x7d5198000000, 135168, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) = 0

$ grep 7d516c000000 strace.txt 
[pid  9738] mprotect(0x7d516c000000, 135168, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) = 0
```

So it looks like the virtual addresses do not come from `mmap` system calls.

I noticed that both of the `mprotect` calls came from `malloc/arena.c`, but how is that possible the address does not come from the `mmap`?